# VNC: GDBus Error:org freedesktop.PolicyKit1 Error.Failed;

Tags: boot-issues, vnc, osmc, desktop

I have tried looking at all forums on this subject, all of them do not work, also the forums referring to this problem are from 2012 to 2015, out of date information.

I am using the latest Raspbian Jessy and it does not matter what one does this error message comes back.

Looking for a answer for the latest Raspbian if possible for 2017.

Any help would be most welcoming.

Thanks for anytime spent trying to solve this.

Comment: Just so you know, the latest Raspbian is not Jessie, it is Stretch. It was released in August 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=96745)?

Basically:

1. First go to: Menu > Preferences > Main Menu Editor
2. Check the box for "Default applications for LXSession"
3. Go to: Menu > Preferences > Default applications for LXSession
4. Under the Core Applications tab, notice that Polkit agent is set to
   lxpolkit. Make the field blank.

Comment: That worked very well, problem being the Pi board GUI is very slow and not responding to commands that well. Appreciate the time taken to solve this problem.  Thanks!!!

Comment: This post was better explained.

Comment: Found this now in the other post down the bottom of the list.